# How to reduce execution time of polyfills.ts in angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, version-control

Angular 9 Polyfills Bundle Javascript Execution Time is very high - Google Pagespeed shows warning

Comment: refer this thread it may help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14871